# What's the difference between "They finished the project by March" and "They had finished the project by March"?

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect, past-simple

What's the difference between

"They finished the project by March" and "They had finished the project by March"?

Can you give contexts when to use one and not the other?

Comment: No, I just need contexts for both sentences to know when one should be used rather than the other. I think context helps best to realize the difference.

Comment: The accepted answer in the proposed duplicate gives example context and usage.

Comment: The title of the question may not seem like it answers your question, but the accepted answer explains in detail what the difference is and will help you understand more sentences than just this one.

Comment: @ColleenV thank you. From what I've understood now: I can say "They had finished the report by March, so they felt relaxed now, not aware that their boss would give them a more difficult task in April"